# Complex survey design with multiple waves

Tags: survey-weights, weighted-data, sample-weighting

The organization I work for has collected data from individuals in multiple waves.  Their goal was to collect 333 individuals in 6 different groups (genderXgroup).  If the first Wave did not reach 333 individuals per group, they planned to collect additional data in a second Wave that utilized the same sampling design as the first Wave.  When creating weights, how should we approach assigning weights to individuals?  I assume that separate weights would be derived for individuals for each Wave.  Is that right?  Alternatively, should the two waves of data be combined to estimate the weights?

To provide additional details about the sample design:
The wave 1 sample was stratified by group (3 groups), sex (M/F), region (4 regions), and age (3 groups), such that there were 3X2X4X3 = 72 strata. Females were oversampled such that there would be equal numbers of males and females in each of the three groups. Of the total selected to respond to surveys, the goal was to collect 333 individuals for each of 6 groups (group X sex = 6 groups). Additionally, rurality and race were utilized as control variables. A Wave 2 was planned to collect the additional number of surveys to obtain the 333 individuals for each group.

Comment: The details matter: please explain how these "waves" worked and what the sample design was.

Comment: The wave 1 sample was stratified by group (3 groups), sex (M/F), region (4 regions), and age (3 groups), such that there were 3X2X4X3 = 72 strata.  Females were oversampled such that there would be equal numbers of males and females in each of the three groups. Of the total selected to respond to surveys, the goal was to collect 333 individuals for each of 6 groups (group X sex = 6 groups).  Additionally, rurality and race were utilized as control variables.  A Wave 2 was planned to collect the additional number of surveys to obtain the 333 individuals for each group.